# Android Studio:How I can manage different exercises in each chapter?

Tags: java, android

I am working on a book app, main menu contains 10 chapters, now each chapter contains different number of exercises, 4, 7, 10 like this.

1) What I want is when user taps on a chapter it loads its exercises, like exercise 1, exercise 2 etc. and when user taps on an exercise it shows a scanned copy of exercise.

how can I do that?

By creating different xml for each chapter?

2) how can I use same imageview to display the selected exercise or  I would have to create imageview for each exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to go with HTML files or web contents on this(To make the app more dynamic),How ever if you only want the java approach you can Make use of fragments

1. Create an Activity for all the fragments to be used as a base
2. Add a list fragment to load the list of chapters from the local database or server or storage etc.
3. On clicking the chapter,Create another fragment with the list of exercises by passing the ID of the user pressed Chapter from Db or Server
4. Create a third fragment for showing the Scanned copy of exercise,when tapped on the list for exercises create it by passing the exercise id and show it on the activity

Comment: I want to go with java as i know java only, so i need only one activity for the whole app? i created one for main menu and 2nd for exercises and 3rd for imageview

Comment: That's why I've added the solution for java Only